# How to select from HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, select, hql

I'm new to HQL and have a SQL expression I need converted but am unable to select the SQL statement is:

```
select SenseDate as Time,SenseValue as Value
from UserData
where NetworkID = '23'
and IODeviceID = '129'
and SenseDate >=  DateAdd("d",-1, GETDATE())
and SenseDate<=GETDATE()
```

I can run this part in HQL without problems:

```
from UserData 
where NetworkID = '23'
and IODeviceID = '129'
and SenseDate >=  DateAdd(d,-1, GETDATE())
and SenseDate<=GETDATE()
```

However I only want the `SenseDate` and `SenseValue` values returned, could someone show me how to select as when I try to add `select SenseDate, SenseValue` etc. I keep getting errors in Netbeans

Answer (score 5):

You can select fields/columns using HQL. Looks like the following:

```
select
    SenseDate,
    SenseValue
from
    UserData
where
    NetworkID = '23'
and
    IODeviceID = '129'
and
    SenseDate >= DateAdd(d, -1, GETDATE())
and
    SenseDate <= GETDATE()
```

When you execute this you will receive a list of arrays of objects:

```
final List<Object[]> values = query.list();
```

Each element in the list represents a found row. The array itself contains the two selected fields in the same order you declared them in the statement.

Answer (score 4):

I think [HQL](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/queryhql.html) has the "new" keyword now.

> select new Family(mother, mate,
>   offspr) from Eg.DomesticCat as mother
>       join mother.Mate as mate
>       left join mother.Kittens as offspr

Similar to projections/resulttransformers in the Criteria world.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to use something like projections.

This means, that you'll have to create a class that will hold the results that you're trying to retrieve.

In your case, this could look something like this:

```
public class SenseUserData
{
    public DateTime SenseDate
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Decimal SenseValue
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public SenseUserData( DateTime date, Decimal value )
    {
       this.SenseDate = date;
       this.SenseValue = value; 
    }
}
```

Then, you'll have to let NHibernate know about the existence of this class.
You can do that, by 'importing' it.
So, this means you do not have to create a mapping file for it, you just have to do this in a hbm file:

```
<import class="myclassname" />
```

And then, you can just do this in HQL:

```
select new SenseUserData (SenseDate, SenseValue) from UserData
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to do what hibernate calls projections.  Here is some info on how to do projections in HQL:

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Hibernate-HQL-in-Depth/1/